# Eclipse Birt - Set style cell table dynamically with Event Handler

Tags: eclipse, report, handler, cell, birt

I have Birt table in a report and i want to create a handler class that change the style color of the cell in the table dynamically if the cell contains the max of the column.

I try this for first step and i hooked the class to the row of the table report.

```
public class RowMinMax implements IRowEventHandler
{

  public void onCreate(IRowInstance rowInstance, IReportContext reportContext)
  {
      double max=0;             
      IRowData rowData = rowInstance.getRowData();
      double cellValue = (double) rowData.getColumnValue("nameColumn");

      if(cellValue>max)
      {
         //change cell style
      }
  } ... //OTHER METHOD INTERFACE
}
```

I can not find a suitable method to find the object cell and set the style (es. font color red).

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: have you managed to solve this? It might help me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? You can achieve this with Javascript in the rptdesign file. No need to use a custom Java class.
First, you should compute the maximum (let's call it "maxValue") using BIRT's aggregation columns - either in the DataSet itself or in the Table item definition.
Next, you can define a function like this in the reports's initialize event:

```
function modifyStyle(cell, row) {
    if (row["nameColumn"] >= row["maxValue"]) {
        cell.getStyle().borderLeftWidth = "3px";
        cell.getStyle().borderRightWidth = "3px";
    }
}
```

In the cell's onCreate event, call the function:

```
modifyStyle(this, row);
```